# Linux Multiple virtual interfaces access through snmp

Tags: linux, interface, virtual, snmp

We had configured net-snmp in a linux machine and configured around 100 virtual interfaces (eth0:x).

And i could not access virtual interfaces through MIB browser.

Can you guide me to discover all virtual interfaces as the part of Linux machine discovery?

Thanks in advance !

~Prabhakar

Answer (score 0):

Use OID `.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2`. It will output all interfaces (both physical and logical) with their SNMP indexes.

For example:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c private 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2
IF-MIB::ifDescr.1 = STRING: lo
IF-MIB::ifDescr.2 = STRING: eth0
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.

our product is using 'ifXTable' mib

Is there any extra configuration required to get all virtual interfaces discovered successfully.